# Member type with multiple bounds

Tags: java, generics

So I just learned that I can

```
public <T extends SomeClass & SomeInterface<OtherClass>> doSomething(T foo);
```

in Java to express that `foo` extends `SomeClass` and also implements `SomeInterface<OtherClass>`. So far, so good.

But how would I assign `foo` in `doSomething()` to a member variable? The class of course does not know anything of the type definition that is attached to the `doSomething()` method.

The context where I need this is a POJO whose constructor needs to be argumented with said `T` and that needs to return the said `T` again.

The closest I came was the following:

```
public class ThisClass implements AnotherInterface<AnotherClass> {

    private final Object obj;

    public <U extends SomeClass & SomeInterface<AnotherClass>> ThisClass(U obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public <U extends SomeClass & SomeInterface<AnotherClass>> U getObject() {
        return (U) obj;
    }
}
```

but I'm unable to wind my head around to get a solution without the unchecked cast.

Comment: @giorashc: His constructor is fine: gerneric type, classname, arguments.

Comment: ohhh sorry my mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you make the class generic:

```
public class ThisClass<U extends SomeClass & SomeInterface<AnotherClass>>
                                   implements AnotherInterface<AnotherClass> {

    private final U obj;

    public ThisClass(U obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public U getObject() {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
ThisClass<String> instance = new ThisClass<>("Foo");
String value = instance.getObject();
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid that, because ThisClass is actually an abstract class that is reimplemented again and I'd have to carry the verbose `U extends SomeClass & SomeInterface<AnotherClass>` in each each derived class, just with another `AnotherClass` parameter. But I guess, this is the only way to do it...?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it can't be done. The problem is Java doesn't have denotable interception type `A&B`.

If Java has that, we can write something like

```
    Pet&Furry pet;

    void set(Pet&Furry pet){ this.pet=pet; }

    Pet&Furry get(){ return pet; }
```

Now, type variables can have interception bounds `A&B`, so one would think we can exploit that

```
    Object pet;

    <U extends Pet&Furry> void set(U pet){ this.pet=pet; }

    <U extends Pet&Furry> U get(){ return (U)pet; }
```

But it's not type safe. Consider

```
    x.set(dog); 
    ...
    Cat cat = x.get();
```

we may live with that risk if we require programmers to mentally keep track of the actual type.